MSBuild: How to get project sdk version (TargetFramework) inside Directory.Build.props file?
I have been playing around with a few MSBuild properties inside a Directory.Builds.props of which the latest is changing location of obj/bin folders. By default the project output is put inside of sdk / TargetFramework version folder e.g. proj/bin/Debug/net8.0/
When the <OutDir> property is used to set custom directory the sdk version is not included. I have looked at the ms docs for a variable but couldn't find one that worked. I have also looked into reading the .csproj file as well but I have had issues finding a solution for getting a specific xml value from the file e.g. TargetFramework. A lot of the docs that pop up are very old as well and I'd prefer not going there if there is a simpler solution.
Example Directory.Build.props file:
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)/builds/$(MSBuildProjectName)/bin/$(Configuration)</OutDir>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Example console project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Example output dir of above would be:
solution/builds/proj/bin/debug/

What I'd like to have with version:
solution/builds/proj/bin/debug/net8.0

How to get the sdk / TargetFramework version?

The Directory.Builds.props and Directory.Builds.targets files can both contain any valid MSBuild code, i.e. both can have properties and targets. The difference between the two files is when they are imported. Directory.Builds.props is imported very early, before the content of the project file and before many of the standard properties have been defined. TargetFramework is defined in the project file after the content of the .props. A quick rule of thumb: default to using the Directory.Builds.targets file. Don't use the Directory.Builds.props file (unless necessary).

See the Microsoft.NET.Sdk SDK documentation, especially the AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath property. Let the SDK build the OutputPath property value. OutDir is initialized with OutputPath. (The MSBuild source code notes that "OutDir and OutputPath are distinguished for legacy reasons, and OutDir should be used if at all possible.")

There is a feature of the dotnet cli, to invoke msbuild to get property values that is pretty hidden unless you know about it :)
You can execute dotnet msbuild Test.csproj --getProperty:<property_name> to simply get the values
For instance dotnet msbuild Test.csproj --getProperty:TargetFramework will output net8.0
Docs for it are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/evaluate-items-and-properties?view=vs-2022
